# How to show Who's online in a user control in masterpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get online users of my website and show the online users name in a repeater.

The reapeter will be in a usercontrol.

How to get online users?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 int i = 0;
 foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
 {
  if (u.IsOnline)
   i++;
 }
```

Note that this is a quick and easy method.. more sophisticated methods using HttpModules would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of when a person is online in your user database.  Have a column which is set to true when a user logs in and set to false when either they log out or their session expires.  To find out who is online, simply query your user database and find the users who have this flag set to true.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a global list and add and remove from that list in every Application's session start and Session End event

Answer (score 0):

Whatever option you use to track the online users, the list will be out of date. The server only knows the requests that are being processed, not what happened thereafter at the browser.

You can not (at least, nor reliably) note when a user navigates away from your site or closes his/her browser. You could only note that the user hasn't come by in the last 20 minutes, so that session should by now be expired.